# Hyperlinking ID's in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formula

So i have a huge list of ID's in Excel (1000's),that all need to by hyperlinked. And the id's are the last part of the URL.

How do i Auto hyperlink the entire column?

Example.

http://www.website.com/cusid=#######

The ####### Being the ID in the Excel Column.

What would be the formula for that. =HYPERLINK("https://www.website.com/custID="????)  would be the base i assume. What do i put in ??? to auto fill the ID after the custID= in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the HYPERLINK function as below:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/cusid=" & A1)
```

with A1 being the location of the ID.

Moreover, if you want to display another text than the full URL on the hyperlink, you can also extend the function as below:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/cusid=" & A1, A1)
```

This will only display the ID number and not the full URL.

You can check here the documentation on the hyperlink function: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010342583.aspx

Comment: yeah, that much im familiar with. what i cant seem to get to work, is doing a entire Colum (about 300+ ID's) at once.  Do i have to do every single one individualy.

Comment: Well not sure I got your point correctly, but you can simply put your formula next to your column of IDs and then drag down the formula to the bottom

Comment: Nope, that does not work. Dont know why, but the Hyperlink does not get the ID extension after it. All i get is #Value boxes.

If i have ID Like so

12345 (http://www.website.com/cusid=12345)
23456 (http://www.website.com/cusid=23456) 

I need them to all hyperlinked. But show up as the ID.  And the columns have 50-500 Id's in them.  

This is starting to get frustrating if i have to do them all one by one.

Comment: Could you provide what function you use exactly? Because it works for me

Comment: If you use this function =HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/cusid=" & A1), and that value in A1 is 12345, then you get http://www.website.com/cusid=12345. If you then drag the function down, you will get all your hyperlinks created. I just tried and it works

Comment: =HYPERLINK("https://xxxxxxx.com/xx/xxxx/CustomerDashboard.aspx?custid=" & A1, A1)

All i get are 0 Values or # Values any way i use that and drag the Green (or blue box for the values) down.. ive tried all variations